# Unknow keyword error for sleep, log to console and get current date in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, selenium, robotframework, ride

I am using below automation script in eclipse.
The same script was running properly previously but now I got new system and I have import it here.
I am getting two errors.
First is unknown keyword error in my script for sleep, log to console and get current date.
Code is as follows.

```
***settings***
Library  Selenium2Library          
Library  DateTime
Library  BuiltIn
Resource    ../Variables.robot
Test Teardown  Close all browsers  

***keywords***
     
  

*** Test Cases ***
TC ID : 1
    [Documentation]  To verify: "Filters  functionality is working"
    ${CurrentDate}   Get Current Date  result_format=%m%d%Y%H%M%S
    Set Screenshot Directory    ${ScreenShotFolder}/${CurrentDate}
    
 sleep  2 

log to console   Total Rows= ${rows}
```

Another error is in red.xml.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Selenium2Library is very old and probably shouldn't be used. You should switch to SeleniumLibrary. That's not the root cause of the problem however.

Comment: Are you getting any Library import errors? Can you check with ``pip list`` command in CMD that the libraries are actually available? If the libraries are not in the default location, you'll need to manually add them to your ``%PYTHONPATH%`` before starting the script.